# how to have full controll of primefaces p:dataGrid pagination with the backing bean?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a p:dataGrid of primefaces that has a pagination on top of the dataGrid.

my goal is to have full control of the pagination buttons so when I click to have some action method associated with it. is there anyone that can explain to me. this is my idea.

```
 <p:dataGrid var="car" value="#{tableBean.cars}" columns="3"  
    rows="12" paginator="true"  
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
   >
```

when I click one of  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}

to be captured from the backing bean so I can do some extra activity prior displaying the page.

if anyone also know how to use getPaginator() client Api and give me an example would be great on their documentation it mentions it but without any snippets of code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primefaces has a `page` event you can use in a `<p:ajax/>` as you would any other event like so

```
 <p:ajax event="page" listener="#{tableBean.myListener}" />
```

Attach this ajax listener to your datatable to achieve the results you want

Alternatively, you could implement the extra processing `load()` method in the primefaces `LazyDataModel`, see an example [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/lazy-jsf-primefaces-datatable_11.html)

Comment: <p:dataGrid var="videos" value="#{pagination.videothumbnailList}" columns="4" rows="16" paginator="true" effect="true" effectSpeed="fast">  this is not working at all. also I saw their example on p:ajax and I try to mimic it yet the navigation button is firing prior the ajax. any other help.

Comment: @kefet, the only other route I can recommend is to implement a primefaces [datamodel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf) in which you can carry out whatever processing you require in the `load()` method of that implementation. Is it that the ajax listener doesn't fire? You might want to file an issue on that. Please update me here if this is the case.