# Spring + JSF with open session pagination not works

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf

I have problem with open session. First of all I use Spring 4.0 + JSF 2.2 + Hibernate 4.3. To provide open session I use **org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter**.
It works partially, I get some entities from database, render the view and lazy loading works correct.

However when after rendering a view I use pagination in p:dataGrid I get lazy initialization exception. How Can I avoid that? I would like that the object will be connected to session as long as the management bean lives. How can I make pagination works without lazy initialization error?

To resolve this problem I try to use check what happen i my management bean. I don't know if I understand it correct but when I use the view scope bean I though that all the time it should be one thread that deal with this bean. But when I print thread id it looks that for every request tomcat use new thread. It's correct behavior? Before, without using spring I use standard open session in view filter and I set **hibernate.current_session_context_class** to **org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext** and everything works perfect. I try to use the same setting here but it cause many errors and I read that when I use filter provided by spring I shouldn't mess with it. I use Tomcat 7.0.34 and hibernate-c3p0 4.3.

Part of web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>         
    </init-param>      
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Hibernate configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>system.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" 
      class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    <!--        c3p0 props-->
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${c3p0.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${c3p0.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${c3p0.maxIdleTime}" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value ="${c3p0.maxStatements}" /> 

</bean>

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.efsf.ostoja" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Managed bean:

```
package com.efsf.ostoja.clientCase.view;

import com.efsf.ostoja.clientCase.logic.interfaces.ICaseService;
import com.efsf.ostoja.clientCase.model.ClientCase;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class MarketMB implements Serializable{

  @Getter @Setter
  private List<ClientCase> cases;

  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{caseService}")
  @Getter @Setter
  private ICaseService service;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
    cases=service.getAllActiveCases();
    System.out.println("Id: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
  }


  public void test(){
    System.out.println("Id2: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
  }
```

}

Method from service:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<ClientCase> getAllActiveCases(){
    return  clientCaseDao.findAllByProperty("status", CaseStatus.NEW);
}
```

Part of my view:

```
<h:form>
  <p:dataGrid value="#{marketMB.cases}" var="c" id="paginatorTable" styleClass="simplePagination" paginator="true" rows="5" columns="1" paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">
    //some div with data here
  </p:dataGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: It won't work. The `OpenSessionInViewFilter` works on a single request as soon as the request is over the `Session` is closed. Hence subsequent requests will fail as the session is not there anymore.

Comment: So what other solution can I use to make it work?

Comment: The documentation (as in - not the demo page but the actual manual) on the primefaces datagrid component should be able to tell you that. Meanwhile I found this related question that should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434703/how-to-have-full-controll-of-primefaces-pdatagrid-pagination-with-the-backing-b